# Can't input data in my array

Tags: java, arrays

Keeps saying "incompatible types String[] cannot be converted to string"

do I have something wrong?

```
public class TimeCard {
    private int employeeNum;
    private String[] clockInTimes = new String[14];
    private String[] clockOutTimes = new String[14];
    private float[] decimalClockIn = new float[14];
    private float[] decimalClockOut = new float[14];
    private float[] timeElapsed =  new float[14];

    public String getClockInTimes()
    {   //im getting the error here
        return clockInTimes;
    }

    public void setClockInTimes(String[] value)
    {    //getting the error here
        clockInTimes = value;
    }  
}
```

Update now it wont let me enter a string within the array.

I'm trying to do it like this:

```
   public class TestTimeCard {

     /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
     public static void main(String[] args) {
     Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

     TimeCard josue = new TimeCard();

     System.out.println("Enter Monday Clock In Times:");
     josue.setClockInTimes(reader.next());
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are returning array but return type is defined as just string.

```
public String[] getClockInTimes()
    {   //im getting the error here
        return clockInTimes;
    }
```

Comment: Okay thanks! I fixed it like you said it it shows no errors.